# nginx controller and ingress - how is nginx controller and ingress linked?

Tags: nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, grafana, nginx-ingress

I've Prometheus/Grafana installed on GKE, and i've setup Nginx Controller + Ingress installed and I'm able to access Prometheus/Grafana using the Nginx Proxy Load Balancer IP.

Question : How is the Ingress & Nginx Controller linked ?
The only reference in the Ingress.yaml is ->

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```

So, if i have another instance of Nginx Controller/Proxy installed (in a different namespace), what are the implications ?
Which Niginx LoadBalancer will be used to access the applications i.e. Prometheus/Grafana ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default deployment of the NGINX Ingress controller is cluster-wide, meaning a single NGINX ingress controller watches/handles Ingress resources created in any/all namespaces.  I assume this is actually what you want.

If you want to have different controllers watching different namespaces, then you can deploy multiple instances and control which namespaces each watches via the `-watch-namespace` command-line arg.

Comment: thanks, @Gari Singh - i'll check this and update